# Regression from multiple time-series

Tags: time-series, neural-networks

I wish to build a deep neural network that takes multiple time-series as input and outputs a single scalar value. The length of each time-series is constant, but the number of time-series can change between data points.

How should i approach this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Wait until I release my package for doing exactly this. Coming soon in a month or two.

Comment: @AminShn Sounds great! In the meantime, could you refer me to any articles about this topic?